# Can you mix past with present?

Tags: tense

> The eternal angel slept on the grass where a shepherd often stayed,
> ignoring all sounds even as the cow grazes.

> He stayed there, ignoring all even as the cow grazes often by.

> You always ignored people, and I bet you still do, ignoring all people as they pass by.

> God slept on the grass, ignoring all even as the cow grazes by.

Is there a way to make it work? Present and past in the same sentence?

Comment: Tense indicates when something happened, so you cannot mix past and present for things that are at the same time.

Comment: Can't you use the present for something that happens regularly?

Comment: Your new example has two clearly different time frames in the two independent clauses. There’s no problem with that.

Comment: Do not mix tenses in this way.  None of these convey a meaningful time frame and each sounds wrong or confused.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix tenses in this way. None of your examples above convey a meaningful time frame and each sounds wrong or confused.

If you want to convey that an action was ongoing in the past, and is still happening in the present, use the past continuous tense:

> You have always ignored people, and I bet you still do.

> He has stayed there, ignoring all, even as the cows have grazed often by.

If you wish to say that something happened in the past, and was completed, and is again happening in the present, there must be two independent clauses:

> You ignored me last Wednesday, and you are ignoring me now!

> God has slept on the grass before. He sleeps there now, and ignores even the grazing cows.